# What is max_value size in logstash file output measured in ?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

I went through the documentation of logstash but could not find answer to this. Could anyone enlighten what is the field `max_value` for `file` output of logstash measured in (bytes, MBs, GBs) ? It is going to be a major driving factor as I do not want to create a file which is 200 MB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you wanted to ask about the parameter `max_size` as `max_value` parameter is not there for a output file.

`max_size` of file output plugins is **not yet supported by logstash.**

They have clearly mention as `NOT YET SUPPORTED` in their site i.e http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/file#max_size.

And if you see the code of `file.rb` in github , they commented as `NOT YET SUPPORTED` and haven't used anywhere in the code.

Hope this helps.